# How to remove input spinner arrows on number inputs using Garden?

Tags: clojurescript

The following CSS removes the input spinner arrows that user agents automatically include when a text field's type is "number."

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

What is the equivalent code in Garden (noprompt/garden)?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent code as expressed in Garden (noprompt/garden) is as follows:

```
(garden.selectors/defselector input)
(garden.selectors/defpseudoelement -webkit-inner-spin-button)
(garden.selectors/defpseudoelement -webkit-outer-spin-button)

(garden.core/css
  [(input (garden.selectors/attr :type := :number))
    [(garden.selectors/& -webkit-inner-spin-button)
     (garden.selectors/& -webkit-outer-spin-button)
      {:-webkit-appearance :none
       :-moz-appearance :textfield
       :margin 0}]]
```